# Show Lync ContactCard in Silverlight 4 by code

Tags: c#, event-handling, silverlight-4.0, lync-2010

I would like to be able to show ContactCard/PopupContactCard control on MouseEnter event of a control.
Does anyone know how to **show** the contact card?
So far I was not able due to internal/protected modifiers of vital methods.
I can do this with the PresenseIndicator control, but not from my custom code in the event handlers.
So any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create either a new page, or a popup section of your existing page, and host a contact-card object in there. Then, on the mouse-enter, pass through the SIP you want to display and show the popup (/show the other page)

The ContactCard control I would probably choose to display is this one: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.lync.controls.contactcard_di_2_lyncctrlslmref.aspx

Or do you mean that you wish to *expand* the ContactCard? I'm not sure if this is possiblem, is the [IsExpanded](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.lync.controls.contactcard.isexpanded_di_2_lyncctrlslmref.aspx) property writable?